# Adding sub module to project causing gradle build failures in Android studio 3.0 with gradle version 4.1

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-3.0

I added sub module library vertical-stepper-form version 0.9.8, while I set dependency of this library on my app module. I was able to do it successfully.

I am using Android Studio 3.0 with gradle version 4.1, few of the classes in project are in kotlin and others in java

When I started gradle sync it gave me this error. The gradle is not building and showing below issues :

/*********************************/

> Information:Gradle tasks [:vertical-stepper-form:generateDebugSources,
>   :vertical-stepper-form:generateDebugAndroidTestSources,
>   :vertical-stepper-form:mockableAndroidJar,
>   :app:generateInstallDebugSources,
>   :app:generateInstallDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar]
>   D:\Devavrata\project/package/src/main/res/abc.xml Error:error:
>   attribute 'com.spireon.install:src' not found.
>   D:\Devavrata\AbcProject\abc-Android\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeInstallDebugResources\stripped.dir\layout\activity_main.xml
>   Error:attribute 'com.spireon.install:src' not found. Error:failed
>   linking file resources. Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for
>   details Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error:
>   check logs for details Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:processInstallDebugResources'.
>
> > Failed to execute aapt Information:BUILD FAILED in 24s Information:7 errors Information:0 warnings Information:See complete output in
> >     console

/********************************/

What I have already tried :

- I tried with changing import lines in xml also changing the android:src and srcCompat properties. Along with build/project cleaning and invalidating the cache.
- Changing this line in gradle.properties

  ```
        android.enableAapt2=false
  ```

Let me know if anyone has faced this issue

Comment: try to run with terminal with --info to see the log and post it plz

Comment: It looks like you're referencing a non-existing resource "com.spireon.install:src" in D:\Devavrata\project/package/src/main/res/abc.xml. Can you post the contents of the file and also where the "com.spireon.install:src" is defined?